# Why Canvas wpf doesn't detect click?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouseevent

This is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Drawing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Height="25" IsEnabled="False" Name="txt"/>
    <Canvas Name="cnv" MouseLeftButtonDown="cnv_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

...and this is my C# code

```
private void cnv_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(cnv);
    p.X += cnv.Margin.Left;
    p.Y += cnv.Margin.Top;
    txt.Text = p.ToString();
}
```

Questions :

1. Even if I click the canvas, the event didn't even fired. I wonder why? Is there anything I missed?
2. In this code, I haven't included any canvas margin, but since I wanna use margin later, is it necessary to add the click position with margin to get a correct value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Canvas` will never auto adjust its size to content and even if it did it has no content in your case so remove `Height="Auto"` and let it fill all available space. Second problem is that `Background` of the `Canvas` won't be initialized (default null value) hence it won't be hit test visible. You need to initialize `Background` to something, `Transparent` for example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Height="25" IsEnabled="False" Name="txt"/>
    <Canvas Name="cnv" MouseLeftButtonDown="cnv_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT**

As for the second question. When you do `GetPosition` you specify relative to which element (in your case you pass `cnv`) so if you would change `Margin` on the `cnv` it would return you position to the top,left corner of the area of `Canvas`. You can test it by changing `Margin` and `Background`, to red for example, of the `Canvas` and clicking in top,left corner of the red rectangle and `Mouse.GetPosition(cnv)` will always return you value close to zero (no matter what's the margin)

Comment: works wonder. but, how about the second question? I'll accept your answer after the second one is answered as well thank you.

Comment: perfect! just to make sure since there's another article said the margin matters. maybe that are another different case then.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the

```
Height="Auto"
```

Attribute of your rows. Can you try to set each Height to 175 and tell if that helped?

Comment: yes it helped. but there's a more comprehensive answer than you. thank you anyway.